# How failover works on Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine

I intend to connect a PHP app (from a server outside Googel Cloud Platform) to Google Cloud SQL. I want to know how can I design the app to failover its database properly.

According to the [manual](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/high-availability):

> When a zonal outage occurs and your master fails over to your failover
>   replica, any existing connections to the instance are closed. However,
>   your application can reconnect using the same connection string or IP
>   address; you do not need to update your application after a failover.

It appears everything is happenning automatically behind the scenes but what if the IP address of the database is out or times out?

Comment: The IP will be moved to the new instance after failover. Nothing needs to happen in the app.

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't reveal [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/high-availability) what back-end is using to provide database service but my assumption is:

- It is using a virtual IP that are routing traffic to master connector, therefore when master fails the backup would start to advertise the virtual IP, this would cause your TCP connection fails.

The comment means if your `mysqli.reconnect` in `php.ini` must be enabled to allow your PHP code automatically connect to the backup MySQL connector when failure occurs. [read here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.configuration.php#ini.mysqli.reconnect)

If your mysqli.reconnect is enabled then you don't have to worry about anything.

Edit: in reply to question raised regarding SQL Transaction -- Of course it will be a mess if the SQL transaction code is not written with a precaution that connection may disconnect at any time during transaction, such scenario must be handled  in code. and when auto-commit is enabled and you are not within a transaction a simple auto-reconnect would solve almost any other scenario.

Comment: PHP's mysqli will break any transaction when the connection is list.  If it automatically re-connects, the partial transaction will be ROLLBACK'd and a new transaction will be started.  This _may_ cause a mess.  You would be better off not auto-reconnecting and treat it as a failed transaction, and have your _code_ restart the transaction.

Comment: Of course it will be a mess if the SQL transaction code is not written with a precaution that connection may disconnect at any time during transaction, such scenario must be handled  in code. and when auto-commit is enabled and you are not within a transaction a simple auto-reconnect would solve almost any other scenario.

Comment: (I felt the need to point the "of course" to the novices reading this thread.)