# Google Cloud SQL MySQL 2nd Gen Concurrent Connections?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

The [pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing#network-egress-pricing) only gives this information for the 1st gen. Does anybody know the concurrent connection limits for the 2nd gen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second Generation instances are configured to allow up to 4000 connections though it does not mean that you can safely run your workload at 4000 connections for a given instance size. Different workloads will have different demands so you still need to monitor/benchmark your application to choose the appropriate instance size.

e.g. You might be able to make 4000 concurrent connections to a n1-standard-1 instance but it's unlikely to perform well for many workloads

Comment: Thanks, do you have a source for this info?

Comment: Me :) I'm an engineer on Cloud SQL.

Comment: Well that's awesome. I wonder why that number isn't published?

Comment: Also, can you kindly shed some light on this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44633747/how-failover-works-on-google-cloud-sql

Comment: The connection limits for Second Generation instances are mentioned in the FAQ: https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#sizeqps